# Bad sound in wine

Tags: 11.04, sound, wine

*I know this is a bug that probably will be fixed in a later version of wine 1.3X. But I was hoping if there is a way to tweak of edit the current version if I have this problem again (I still have it).*

At first everything was working perfectly, but then after 10 minutes I got a bad sound.
I still get the bad sound and it's not localized to a specific application it's also in the wine test sound function.

wine version: **wine-1.3.31**

I have the winealsa driver. It's a new interface and all the old fixes doesn't work.

in the default selesctions you can choose **default**, **System deafult** or **HDMI** (external).

[image]

Comment: Wine 1.3 is the development version. Does this happen in Wine 1.2 too?

Comment: wine 1.2 doesn't even work for me...

Comment: If possible, select the pulse driver. If not, call the wine application with `pasuspender` ahead.

Comment: tell me how to? I don't know this new interface....

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the details on how to use aquaherd's suggestion of pasuspender.

pasuspender will bypass the pulseaudio system for a given program. To try this, open a terminal window (Press Alt+F2 and type `gnome-terminal`). Then try the following command substituting  whatever windows program you want to run for the final argument:

`cd .wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/SomethingEleseHere`
`wineserver -k #stop wine if it is running`
`pasuspender -- wine SomeApplicationHere.exe`

You can also try
`pasuspender -- winecfg`
to run the configuration and test speakers with pulseaudio suspended